# Past tense + will

Tags: will-would

This article talks about expected situations next week:
https://www.rnz.co.nz/news/national/498549/parliament-protest-organisers-told-by-police-to-keep-it-peaceful

It says: He said police will be keeping an eye on vehicles in convoys.
Why isn't it : He said police would be... ?

Comment: People speak like  they  speak. And this is an acceptable way to say this though in writing only would would work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [He said he will attend the party held this weekend. (mixing of tenses).](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/316112/he-said-he-will-attend-the-party-held-this-weekend-mixing-of-tenses) Also [Modal verbs in reported speech](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13370/modal-verbs-in-reported-speech) and [Verb Tense Consistency: How do I distinguish these two sentences?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/253723/), among others.

Answer (score 1):

It seems quite logical to me:

He said (happened in the past eg five minutes ago) people will be keeping an eye on vehicles (something that is going to happen in the future eg next week).

Answer (score 0):

The difference often comes down to the recency of the utterance that’s being reported (not of the report itself, but off its topic). If it’s expected or understood that the police don’t often change their behavior regarding the monitoring of convoys, or anyway that they likely wouldn’t have had time to change that behavior, then the future (*will*) is natural. It also offers information that may be more useful owing to its currency: “Hey, if you’re planning to take part in a caravan, be aware that the police **say** they **are** are monitoring them.”