# The usage of Reported Speech

Tags: usage, reported-speech

> “I will do it”

1. He said he would do it
2. He said he will do it

My question is when can I use these two versions, 1 and 2. In which situations is it correct to use version 1 or version 2?
In other words when do I need to switch tenses?

Comment: We usually "backshift" in such contexts (e.g. - *He said his name **was** John*). But we don't *have* to - both versions are fine. *Except* if the time for doing it has passed - if it was my birthday yesterday, it's not idiomatic to say *He said he will come to my birthday party.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modal verbs in reported speech](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13370/modal-verbs-in-reported-speech) Also [Reported Speech - Backshifting or not?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/241613/) and [Verb Tense Consistency: How do I distinguish these two sentences?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/253723/) and [He said he will attend the party held this weekend. (mixing of tenses)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/316112/he-said-he-will-attend-the-party-held-this-weekend-mixing-of-tenses), among others.

Answer (score 0):

I add some context and summarise what @FumbleFingers said.

Edit

If the party is on 7 Jan, and someone said on 4 Jan "I will do it" in response to a request to book a table by 5 Jan, both examples can be used on 5 Jan if there is still time for the task.  Backshifting is normal but not mandatory.

Only example 1 is possible on 6 Jan because the chance to book the table has passed.

Comment: It is more complex than *The party is on January 7th.* That is not sufficient as context to say which sentence should be used.

Comment: The party is on January 7. On January 4, Albert says *We need somebody who will book at table at her preferred restaurant by tomorrow.* Robert replies *I will do it.* On January 6, would you say *He said he will do it.* or *He said he would do it.*?

Comment: That's making it complicated. If the table needed to be booked by Jan. 5, on 6th you say 'He said he would do it'. But if the party hasn't happened yet, 'He said he will come' and 'He said he would come' are both possible.

Comment: Thanks @Kate Bunting and apaderno.  I have edited my answer.